# Ignore nulls in SQL

Tags: oracle, null

I'm using Oracle SQL and i need some help with a query. I have the following table:

```
Time     | Type | Value_A | Value_b | Loaded time sequence 
11:00:37 |   A  | Null    |  30     |      1
11:00:37 |   A  | 40      |  Null   |      2
11:00:37 |   B  | Null    |  20     |      3
11:00:37 |   B  | Null    |  50     |      4
11:00:38 |   C  | 50      |  Null   |      5
11:00:38 |   D  | Null    |  30     |      6
11:00:38 |   D  | 10      |  Null   |      7
11:00:38 |   D  | Null    |  5      |      8
```

For each `Type` i want to take the last loaded values of `Value_a` and `value_b` which are not NULL. Here is the expected output table:

```
Time     | Type | Value_A | Value_b
11:00:37 |   A  | 40      |  30    
11:00:37 |   B  | Null    |  50    
11:00:38 |   C  | 50      |  Null    
11:00:38 |   D  | 10      |  5
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test data suggests that the TIME and TYPE are linked, and that the values always rise with time.  In which case this solution will work:

```
select Time
       , Type
       , max(Value_A) as Value_A
       , max(Value_B) as Value_B
from your_table
group by Time
         , Type
```

However, I think your posted data is unlikely to be representative, so you'll need a more sophisticated solution.  This solution uses the LAST_VALUE() analytic function:

```
select distinct Time
       , Type
       , last_value(Value_A ignore nulls) 
           over (partition by time, type order by Loaded_time_sequence
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) Value_A
       , last_value(Value_B ignore nulls) 
           over (partition by time, type order by Loaded_time_sequence
               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) Value_B
from t23
;
```

Here is [the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79f1d3) (although the site appears to be broken at the moment).

This may still not be the most correct answer.  It depends on the actual data.  For instance, what should happen when you have an entry for `TYPE=A` at `TIME=11:00:39` ?

Comment: My posed data was random. I didn't mean to raise it by time. I've just edited it. Please look at D values for example. We should not have to consider the values.

Comment: The values should be grouped by `TIME` and `Type`, so there is no problem with `TYPE=A` at `TIME=11:00:39`. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it would be as simple as aggregating with `MAX()`:

```
SELECT time, type, MAX(value_a) AS value_a, MAX(value_b) AS value_b
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY time, type;
```

If `time` is a `TIMESTAMP` then you may want to group by `TRUNC(time, 'SS')`

Comment: It would give me the max values for each `Type`, and i want the last loaded value. The last loaded value can be the min values.

Comment: @Omri - just as I suspected.  You really should have posted sample data which reflects your scenario.  Help us to help you.

Comment: My posed data was random. I didn't mean to raise it by time. I've just edited it. Please look at D values for example. We should not have to consider the values.

Comment: I am still not 100% clear on how the value of `time` is linked. What if the most recent non-NULL value for `value_a` has a different `time` value than the most recent non-NULL value for `value_b` but for the same type?